# parsley.js not working in laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-5.4, parsley.js

I am trying to use parsley.js to validate the user input in client validation but no matter what I tried it doesn't work and have already taken these steps below.

1. Have downloaded parsley.js from http://parsleyjs.org/dist/parsley.min.js
2. Then add the path to the script like this:  (This is added to the `master.blade.php` which all other pages extend).
3. After which I add `data-parsley-validate` to the form that I want to be validated. And this is the form and how I did it.

   ```
   @extends('master')
   @section('content')

   <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
         <div class="panel panel-default">
           <div class="panel-heading">AJAX Register</div>
           <div class="panel-body">
             <form class="form-horizontal" id="registration" method="POST" action="{{ url('users/register') }}" data-parsley-validate="">
               {!! csrf_field() !!}

               <div class="form-group">
                 <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Name</label>
                 <div class="col-md-6">
                   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" required="">
                 </div>
               </div>

               <div class="form-group">
                 <label class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>
                 <div class="col-md-6">
                   <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" required="">
                 </div>
               </div>

               <div class="form-group">
                 <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>
                 <div class="col-md-6">
                   <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" required="">
                 </div>
               </div>

               <div class="form-group">
                 <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Confirm Password</label>
                 <div class="col-md-6">
                   <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" id="password_confirmation" data-parsley-equalto="#password" required="">
                 </div>
               </div>

               <div class="form-group">
                 <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ladda-button" data-style="expand-left" data-size="s" data-color="green">
                     <i class="fa fa-btn fa-user"></i> Register
                   </button>
                   <a href="{!! asset('login/facebook') !!}">
                     <div class="btn btn-md btn-primary ladda-button" data-style="expand-left" data-size="s" data-color="blue"> <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Login with Facebook </div>
                   </a>
                 </div>
               </div>
             </form>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>

   @endsection
   ```

Comment: Please provide an actual working example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using jQuery wrap your parsley code in:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // your code here
})
```

Also post your script code with parsley.

Comment: That is it. I don't have any script for parsley except the parsley.min.js file which I put inside the js folder